# How to remove a new-line character (\n) from copy-pasted text in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a code which replace some characters (space, tabulator) of string introduced by the user, and then shows the text:

```
    System.out.println("Text:");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        String text = bufferedReader.readLine();
        text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
        text = text.replaceAll(" ", "");
        text = text.replaceAll("\t", "");
        System.out.println(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

But when I paste a text of varios lines:

```
First Substring Introduced
Second Substring Introduced
Third Substring Introduced
```

it shows just the substring before the first newline like:

```
firstSubtringIntroduced
```

I want to obtain the next result of whole pasted text:

```
FirstSubstringIntroducedSecondSubstringIntroducedThirdSubstringIntroduced
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading **just one line**, the first one:

```
String text = bufferedReader.readLine();  //just one line
```

That's why you got that output that only shows the first line processed. You should make a **loop** in order to read all of the lines you are entering:

```
 while((text=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
 {
    text = text.replaceAll("\n", "");
    text = text.replaceAll(" ", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\t", "");

    System.out.print(text);
 }
```

The first loop will print *FirstSubtringIntroduced*, the second *SecondSubstringIntroduced*, and so on, until all the lines are processed.

Answer (score 1):

Try aggregating all lines together, after removing tab and space from each line:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String text = "";
try {
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text = text.replaceAll("[\t ]", "");
        sb.append(text);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

The issue here is that your `BufferedReader` is reading one line at a time.

As an alternative, and closer to your current solution, you could just using `System.out.print`, which does not automatically print a newline, instead of `System.out.println`:

```
try {
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text = text.replaceAll("[\t ]", "");
        System.out.print(text);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: I like the second solution (the best one at the moment). But how can I exit from the while condition? It seems it forces me to introduce Enter twice now and that produce some fail in following implementation.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even giving inputs, as your sample code does not hint at this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `String#replaceAll` expects a regular expression. `String#replace` replaces *all occurrences* of the first argument with the second argument (which is what you want).

```
System.out.println(text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""));
```

The method names are a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Text:");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader);
        ) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                stringBuilder.append(scanner.next());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

I do think this is what you need.

Comment: When will be the System.out statement executed?

Comment: @lsi when `System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());` invoke.